# How to initialize whole Python module and import all classes without needing to reference module name for every call?

Tags: python, import, module

Suppose I have a module named 'module1', which has many classes. I want to use all of their classes in my main controller **main**.py . I can import whole module with `import module1`, however, I assume that the class names in 'module1' are unique and I do not want to reference module1 every time I call its function such as `module1.class1()`.

How can I import the whole contents of a module without explicitly having to state class/function names and still being able to refer to them without stating the module name.

Such as:

```py
    # module1.py.
    class Class1():
        pass
    
    class Class2():
        pass
```

```py
    # __main__.py
    import module1
    
    # The following will not work.
    object1 = Class1()
    object2 = Class2()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `*` import pattern

```py
from module1 import *
```

This lets you use everything inside that module without referencing it.

```py
from module1 import *

instance = Class1()
```

However, this is generally discouraged. For reasons why, some additional reading:

- [Why is "import *" bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad)
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-import-star-in-python-is-a-bad-idea/

Comment: That's usually recommended against as it's easy to import *really unexpected* things and create gnarly dependencies. For instance it'll also "import" everything else that `module1` defines *or imports*. `from module1 import Class1, Class2` works fine though.

Comment: @Masklinn I 100% agree, I added a link to some additional reading on why not to do this. Feel free to suggest alternative/additional resources